# Vuetify datatable with Axios call

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

I am attempting to populate a datatable with an axios call. However I am unable to actually see the data in the table on my site. If I inspect the table I can see that the data is indeed there, but not visible to the end user. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong here?

**component**

```
    <template>
    <v-data-table 
                  :items="posts"
                  :items-per-page="5"
                  item-key="post_id"
                  hide-default-header
                  class="elevation-1"
                  :footer-props="{
      showFirstLastPage: true,
      firstIcon: 'mdi-arrow-collapse-left',
      lastIcon: 'mdi-arrow-collapse-right',
      prevIcon: 'mdi-minus',
      nextIcon: 'mdi-plus'
    }"></v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
    import PostService from '../services/PostService'
    export default {
        name: 'ViewPost',
        data() {
            return {
                posts: []
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.loadPosts()
        },
        methods: {
            loadPosts() {
                this.posts = []
                const posts = PostService.getAllPosts(posts).then(response => {
                    this.posts = response.data.recordset
                })
                console.log(posts)
            }
        }
    };
</script>   
</style>
```

**console of web browser**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/14vI8.png

Note the paging on the bottom right of the photo... It shows 1-5 of 7 results. There are indeed 7 items in my database that are populating my posts array. So I don't feel its an issue with my axios call. You as well can see the data in the vue tab of the console with my data. Any thoughts here?

Comment: You need to declare headers, with the column names and values.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. ohhh that was way too painful to be so simple... feel free to add as answer , and I will gladly give you the points. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the datatable headers; at least the text (column name) and value (property in your object) as documented in https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/

> **headers**: `TableHeader[]`
>
> An array of objects that each describe a header column.
>
> ```
> {
>   text: string
>   value: string
>   align?: 'start' | 'center' | 'end'
>   sortable?: boolean
>   filterable?: boolean
>   groupable?: boolean
>   divider?: boolean
>   class?: string | string[]
>   width?: string | number
>   filter?: (value: any, search: string, item: any) => boolean
>   sort?: (a: any, b: any) => number
> }
> ```